# google says my site is not mobile-friendly and it is

Tags: mobile

I have created a site, complete with responsive layout which works well.

Apparently google thinks the site isn't mobile friendly, and has listed a whole pile of resoures that I notice are included in this text in the robots.txt file

```
Disallow: /administrator/
Disallow: /bin/
Disallow: /cache/
Disallow: /cli/
Disallow: /components/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /installation/
Disallow: /language/
Disallow: /layouts/
Disallow: /libraries/
Disallow: /logs/
Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /modules/
Disallow: /plugins/
Disallow: /templates/
Disallow: /tmp/
```

It looks like I need to allow access to some of these files/folders including media, templates and plugins

I am concerned that google will then be putting up administrator type pages within its search results

What should I do?

Is it ok to do this - and which ones should I allow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some more rooting around I just made image, media and templates viewable to robots. Now my site is friends with google.